# How to make text in a scanned pdf appear rounder/smoother/nicer?

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat, font-smoothing

I have a scanned pdf and the text in this pdf looks a bit too slim and unsmooth and thus makes it harder to read. Is there a way to optimize the text in the pdf so that it can look rounder/smoother/nicer? This pdf is already searchable. I give several pictures below to illustrate the desired optimization:

(please don't be confused abut the relative size of the pictures below. The original and the desired version of the same word are supposed to be of the same size. Somehow stackexchange renders the desired version slightly larger)

Original:[image]

Original:[image]

Original:[image]

Desired:[image]

Original:[image]

Desired: [image]

I have adobe acrobat available for use.

Comment: Scan at a higher resolution, i.e., more dots per inch (DPI)

Comment: My primary concern is to optimize an already-scanned document. It is tedious to redo the scan.

Comment: Too late; not enough info was captured.

Comment: if you are able to get OCR to work you might be able to recreate the document pasting the recognised text over the old. Otherwise I would guess you will need to rescan.

Comment: What do you mean by "recreate the document pasting the recognised text over the old?" Does it mean replacing the old scanned text with typeset text? How exactly do I do this (is there a link to a tutorial)? I do have OCR in my acrobat.

Comment: In Acrobat, you have the Enhance Scanned Document functionality. See if that can provide some improvements. For the OCR settings, try Editable Text and Images

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ScanTailor Advanced](https://github.com/vigri/scantailor-advanced), it has a Black and White image processing mode where you can change Threshold out of 3 possible methods - Otsu, Sauvola, Wolf and make text thinner or thicker.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1173911)